# Halide process average of color image

Tags: c++, tuples, halide

I am starting to learn Halide. What I want to do is apply a filter based on the average value of an RGB image. Essentially, I am trimming the highlights and the lows for further processing. I need the average across all channels as it would not be appropriate to clip a pixel with a value of (250, 10, 12), but it would be appropriate for say (250, 252, 253).

The following is what I am doing. All I am asking is is there a better way (a more halide-y way) to do it? Would be happy for some pointers.

```
Expr getAvgF(Expr r, Expr g, Expr b) {
    Expr rf = cast<float>(r);
    Expr gf = cast<float>(g);
    Expr bf = cast<float>(b);
    return (rf + gf + bf) / 3.0f;
}

Buffer<uint8_t> filterRGB(Buffer<uint8_t> rgbInput, float low, float high) {
    Var x, y, c;
    Expr cR = rgbInput(x, y, 0);
    Expr cG = rgbInput(x, y, 1);
    Expr cB = rgbInput(x, y, 2);

    Expr avg = getAvgF(cR, cG, cB);
    cR = select(avg > low, cR, cast<uint8_t>(0));
    cG = select(avg > low, cG, cast<uint8_t>(0));
    cB = select(avg > low, cB, cast<uint8_t>(0));
    cR = select(avg < high, cR, cast<uint8_t>(255.0f));
    cG = select(avg < high, cG, cast<uint8_t>(255.0f));
    cB = select(avg < high, cB, cast<uint8_t>(255.0f));

    Func filter;
    filter(x, y, c) = select(c == 0, cR, c == 1, cG, cB);
    filter.bound(c, 0, 3).unroll(c);

    return filter.realize(rgbInput.width(), rgbInput.height(), 3);
}
```

Tutorial 13 seems to imply that tuples could be used for processing color images. However, they produce multiple output buffers.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Quick air code to hopefully get you moving until you get a better answer.

```
Func avg;
avg(x,y) = (cast<float>(rgbInput(x,y,0)) + cast<float>(rgbInput(x,y,1)) +cast<float>(rgbInput(x,y,2))) / 3.0f;
Func output;
output(x,y,c) = select(avg(x,y)>high, 255,
                       select(avg(x,y)<low, 0, rgbInput(x,y,c));

output.bound(c,0,3).unroll(c);
```

Comment: Thank you much, this is quite useful!